# Issues installing NUBIC/surveyor gem in Rails 3.2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, surveyor-gem

I am trying to install the [NUBIC surveyor](https://github.com/NUBIC/surveyor) gem in a Rails 3.2.3 app. I did the following steps:

1) Created a new Rails 3.2.3 project

```
 $ rails new surveyor
```

2) Added the surveyor gem

```
 gem "surveyor"
```

3) Ran

```
bundle install
```

4) Generated the assets

```
 script/rails generate surveyor:install
```

5) Ran migrations

```
 bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

6) Then when I tried the "kitchen sink" survey

```
 rake surveyor FILE=surveys/kitchen_sink_survey.rb
```

I encountered the following error:

> survey rake aborted! Can't mass-assign protected attributes: title, reference_identifier

I found this [issue on github (#302)](https://github.com/NUBIC/surveyor/issues/302) regarding the mass-assignment of protected attributes and it seems as if the issue was closed and the gem was updated. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) I needed to specify the dependent gems in the Gemfile, which I hadn't done. I had only specified the surveyor gem.

```
 gem 'surveyor', :git => 'git://github.com/NUBIC/surveyor.git' 
 gem 'haml', '~> 3.1.3'
 gem 'sass'
 gem 'fastercsv', '~> 1.5.4'
 gem 'formtastic', '~> 1.2.4'
 gem 'uuidtools', '~> 2.1'
 gem 'mustache', '0.99.4'
 gem 'rabl', '~>0.6.6'
 gem 'rake', '0.9.2'
```

2) The rake version required by surveyor (0.9.2) was different than what I was running (0.9.2.2) so I needed to add `bundle exec` before all of the rake commands in the [surveyor README install instructions](https://github.com/NUBIC/surveyor).

Comment: For future reference: this is no longer necessary with current versions of Surveyor.

Answer (score 1):

As Rhett mentioned, this is no longer an issue with current versions of surveyor. You could try `bundle update surveyor`, or specify a more recent version of surveyor in your Gemfile, e.g.

```
gem 'surveyor', '~>1.3.0'
```

You may also need to run `bundle exec rake surveyor FILE=...`